# How to extend ScalaDoc Annotations?

Tags: scala, annotations, scaladoc

Is there a way to add a new ScalaDoc annotation? Specifically, I'd like to define `@business` annotation as an extension of `@note`.

This, obviously, should be able to behave as the `@note`:

```
/**
  * @business A business description of the item.
  */
def definition: _ = ???
```